# PHP : Can't create automatic query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a search engine for a webpage. I use the code below. The problem is, that I have to build the queries from different strings and if the system searches for matching in strings, quote marks are needed.

```
$sql = "SELECT TIT,VNEV,KNEV,NEME,MEGY,LCVAR,APOLG FROM TORZS LEFT OUTER JOIN VEGZETTSEG ON TORZS.ID = VEGZETTSEG.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZTAPASZTALAT ON TORZS.ID = SZTAPASZTALAT.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZAKTANFOLYAM ON TORZS.ID = SZAKTANFOLYAM.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORM ON TORZS.ID = INFORM.ID WHERE ";
for ($i = 0;$i < count($searchcategs);$i++) {
    $sql = $sql . $searchcategs[$i];
    $sql = $sql . " = ";
    $sql = $sql . $searchvals[$i];
    $sql = $sql . " ";
}
```

An alternative version:

```
$sql = "SELECT TIT,VNEV,KNEV,NEME,MEGY,LCVAR,APOLG FROM TORZS LEFT OUTER JOIN VEGZETTSEG ON TORZS.ID = VEGZETTSEG.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZTAPASZTALAT ON TORZS.ID = SZTAPASZTALAT.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZAKTANFOLYAM ON TORZS.ID = SZAKTANFOLYAM.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORM ON TORZS.ID = INFORM.ID WHERE ";
for ($i = 0;$i < count($searchcategs);$i++) {
    $sql = $sql . $searchcategs[$i];
    $sql = $sql . " = '";
    $sql = $sql . $searchvals[$i];
    $sql = $sql . "' ";
}
```

None of them seems to work, I got

> SELECT TIT,VNEV,KNEV,NEME,MEGY,LCVAR,APOLG FROM TORZS LEFT OUTER JOIN VEGZETTSEG ON TORZS.ID = VEGZETTSEG.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZTAPASZTALAT ON TORZS.ID = SZTAPASZTALAT.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN SZAKTANFOLYAM ON TORZS.ID = SZAKTANFOLYAM.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORM ON TORZS.ID = INFORM.ID WHERE

for the query even though the searchcateg and searchval arrays are existing and not empty.

Comment: Wow, using uppercase table- and column names does wonders for the readability of the query! But you should actually use a prepared statement so that you don't have to quote any of the values. And use a white-list for the column names.

Comment: What's the content of $searchcategs ? And you have a "WHERE"  clause with a for loop but no "AND" or "OR" operators in it.

Comment: $searchcateg contains the possible column names. There are almost 40-50 different columns in the database and each has to be searched for custom values. In this state AND and OR are not needed yet.

Comment: When there is more than 1 item in `$searchcateg` you need `AND` or `OR` as you will generate invalid sql otherwise.

Comment: Check the value returned by `count($searchcategs)` - just in case it returns 0. Unfortunatley, this question cannot really be answered without sample `$searchcategs` and `$searchvals`.

Comment: It doesn't return 0. For example $searchcategs can be like ["city","university","last name"] and $searchvals contains the corresponding values that the user is looking for.  and the Most columns contain strings so I need to put two quote marks around the keyword that I'm searching for in this automatic program. The problem is that when I try to insert these two quote marks it breaks the concatenated string and the code doesn't work.

Comment: You wrote that even the version where you do not have single quotes does not return anything in the where clause, so you cannot really blame the single quotes.

Comment: I tried the same query in terminal and it worked. When I search for a city name, and I omit the quotes, the string construction works in PHP, I got the long .... WHERE city = Quahog expression, but it doesn't work in mysql because the data type is string and there are no quotes. In case I try to insert the quotes into the query construction part the expression for the query breaks because some parts get omitted.